# How to create new variable based on accumulation of additions with previous variable

Tags: r

I want to generate an accumulating total duration based on each additional value in the new vector.

I can manually display what I'm trying to achieve but cannot complete this task with code. The aim is to create a script that will automate the 'total_duration' column based on the 'duration' column.

```
duration=c(1.5,8.9,3,6.2)
total_duration=c(1.5,10.4,13.4,19.6)
duration_df=data.frame(duration,total_duration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the base function `cumsum()`

```
total_duration = cumsum(duration)
[1]  1.5 10.4 13.4 19.6
```

Comment: Great thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `cumsum` function. Modifying your code gets us:

```
duration <- c(1.5,8.9,3,6.2)
total_duration <- cumsum(duration)
duration_df <- data.frame(duration,total_duration)
```

If you want to modify an existing dataframe `df`, you can do `df$b <- cumsum(df$a)`.